# ora-01036 generated when run procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hellow i write procedure, but have mistake can your help me. Near the code of my procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE lol(

   p_U                in  number    
)

 IS
BEGIN

 insert into GTABLE_LOG
   select t.*,
          sysdate as dat
     from GTABLE t
    where q_ID = p_U;

 delete from gTable where Uniq_ID = p_U;

EXCEPTION
  when others then
    null;
END lol;
```

the mistake as 01036

when i try do, it is all do nice, but when in procedure generate mistake

```
insert into GTABLE_LOG
   select t.*,
          sysdate as dat
     from Turchin.TicketingTable t
    where q_ID = p_U;
```

Comment: For a start, you have `/*` on the second row; is that a typo? Secondly, you have `delete from gTable where Uniq_ID = p_UID;` ... but you haven't defined `p_UID`. Also, why `when others then null;` in your exception block? Do you deliberately want to hide any errors? It won't aid you when you try debugging this procedure...

Comment: when others then null it is need, another mistake it is bad wririte

Comment: `when others then null` means that if the insert or delete fails for any reason it will be silent and you'll have no idea what happened - or that there was a problem at all. And is `gTable` really a variable you're passing in? Anyway... please show how you are calling the procedure, it seems likely that call itself is the problem.

Comment: @VasyPupkin you would be far better off to explicitly state all the column names in your insert statement. eg. `insert into gtable_log (col1, col2, col3, ...) select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, ... from gtable t where ...`. That might help solve your issue

Comment: @AlexPoole looks like the insert/delete is an archive operation.

Comment: @Boneist - yes, read that as being the same table, but it's not! Must have been looking at the select...

Comment: begin
  -- Call the procedure
  lol(23655782);
end;

Comment: Better comment/remove the exception block for debugging purpose and post the error here. Later you can add it back.

Comment: i  delete exception block then i see ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512: at "Iol", line 14 ORA-06512. I think i need add some grant  to decide my problem with procedure

Comment: So, Now it is clear. Either the table does not exist or a spelling mistake and probably in your case it is a permission issue.

Comment: It is also clear: You should put a big sign above your desk - "NEVER USE 'WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL' TO HIDE EXCEPTIONS". `when others then null` does not fix your errors, it only hides them so you can pretend the code is correct even when it isn't. `when others then null` should be illegal, it should be removed from PL/SQL and all other languages (I've seen that done a lot in VBA too.)